# Users Admin with MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to figure out where I'm wrong. 
I've created an *admin* role in the Startup.cs Configure function.
I've added a simple web page, that works correctly and shows the users list.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.ViewModels.Account.UserIndexViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UsersList";
}

<h2>Users List</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="UserDetails" asp-route-id="@item.UserName">Details</a> |
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

When I'm trying to get the details of the user, the cshtml page generates correctly the address Account/UserDetails/NameSurname and the UserDetails function in the AccountController.cs is called:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public IActionResult UserDetails(string userName)
{
    return View();
}
```

The problem is that userName is not a string. I've tried to define the argument as object, but I cannot see in the debugging which kind of object is.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to the problem, maybe not the most elegant. 
Instead of using the call using the new asp-action keyword, I used the old fashioned @Html.ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "UserDetails", "Account", routeValues: new { userName = item.userName })
```

This way, the UserDetails function in the AccountController is correctly invoked and the parameter correctly routed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

**First thing:**

> The problem is that userName is not a string. I've tried to define the argument as object, but I cannot see in the debugging which kind of object is.

This is because you use `userName` as action parameter and probably you use default route with `id`, so default `id` isn't mapped to `userName`.

You have 3 options:

- change action parameter to `id` -> `public IActionResult UserDetails(string id)`
- or add new route with `userName` in Startup.cs

  ```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
      routes.MapRoute(
         name: "userdetails",
         template: "Account/UserDetails/{userName?}",
         defaults: new { controller="Account", action="UserDetails" });

      routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
  ```
- or use link like `Account/UserDetails?userName=xxx` instead of `Account/UserDetails/NameSurname`

*In my opinion 1 option is good practice, because default route is sufficient in your scenario, and the new routes should be added only if they are really necessary.*

**Second things:**

> You have construction:
> < a asp-action="UserDetails" asp-route-id="@item.UserName">Details< /a>

There is mistake related to my explanation above - you have assigned value to **id** (`asp-route-id`), but should be assigned to **userName** (`asp-route-userName`)

`<a asp-action="UserDetails" asp-route-userName="@item.UserName">Details</a>`

That construction is quite clever and give you proper link according to your configuration of routes:

- In your case (I assume default route) it give you something like:
  `Account/UserDetails?userName=JohnDoe`
- However if you update action parameter to `id` or you add new route (like example above), it give you URL like `Account/UserDetails/JohnDoe`

*Hope this helps :)*